# Infinite loop with GTK main loop

Tags: rust, gtk

I am writing a GTK application to display a system tray icon and capture user inputs from keyboard. I have written an inifinite loop to capture user inputs. But how to make it work with gtk main loop? Thanks in advance for any idea.

My try:-

```rust
            use device_query::{DeviceQuery, DeviceState, Keycode};


            let device_state = DeviceState::new();
            let mut started = false;
            loop {
                let keys: Vec<Keycode> = device_state.get_keys();

                match keys.last() {
                    Some(key)=>{
                        match key {
                            Keycode::LControl=>{
                                started = true;
                            }
                            Keycode::RControl=>{
                                started = true;
                            }
                            Keycode::F6=>{
                                if started {
                                    println!("Fired");
                                }
                                started = false;
                            }
                            _=>{
                                started = false;
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    None=>{}
                }

            }

            gtk::main();
```

Comment: A timer maybe? You do not want to do this code as fast as possible, but so many times per second.

Comment: @rodrigo Thanks. It worked.

Comment: Maybe you are aware but just in case: this is unlikely to work on Wayland which is by now the default on most distros (because what you are writing is essentially a keylogger)